# How to add facebook sharing button on a webpage for each articles on a webpage individually

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am making a website and have a webpage which contains almost ten articles listed on it.

I Want to add Facebook sharing buttons for every articles. I have added the following code for all articles

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.simplesharebuttons.com" target="_blank">
```

But this shares only the url of that article. I want to pass description and image url as well.

I know it can be done using  Open Graph, but how do i do it for all the articles.

Is there a way to dynamically pull description and image link?

Thanks

Comment: *"I know it can be done using Open Graph, but how do i do it for all the articles."* Depends on how the HTML for your articles is generated.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

All you need to do is take the code they provide (ie. HTML5), and place it after the body tag. Then the code for the plugin (ie. the fb-share-button), can go on the page where each individual article would be displayed.

For the plugin section:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.google.com" data-type="button_count"></div>
```

The area that says dara-href="http:.....", this you will need to either, individually, replace with the URL of the article you want to share.  Or, if you are able, you can customize this to PHP pages, and just rewrite to always read the URL of the article page for you.